# How to assign a column the value that is above it only if a condition is met?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a dataframe where I have some empty values in a column. I need those empty values to be assigned to the next real value above them, whether it is 1 row above or 4 rows above. But, the caveat is that I only needs those empty values to be filled in if a certain condition is met.

Dataframe currently looks like:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 1 | NaN |
| 1 | NaN |
| 2 | 150 |
| 2 | NaN |
| 2 | NaN |
| 3 | NaN |
| 3 | NaN |
| 4 | 60 |
| 5 | 70 |
| 5 | NaN |

I need it to look like:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 1 | 100 |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 150 |
| 2 | 150 |
| 2 | 150 |
| 3 | NaN |
| 3 | NaN |
| 4 | 60 |
| 5 | 70 |
| 5 | 70 |

So the first value for each grouping in column A needs to be carried out for that grouping in column B...all rows with a 1 in column A should have the same column B value. All rows with a 2 in column A should have the same column B value. The value it should be will always be the first value. In other words, the first row a new value comes up in column A will contain the correct value in Column B that should be carried down.

I really have no idea how to approach this. I was thinking about using groupby but that didn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think groupby is the way to go:

```
g = df.groupby('Column A')
df['Column B'] = g.ffill()
```

Output:

```
    Column A    Column B
0   1           100.00
1   1           100.00
2   1           100.00
3   2           150.00
4   2           150.00
5   2           150.00
6   3           NaN
7   3           NaN
8   4           60.00
9   5           70.00
10  5           70.00
```

Comment: Thank you!! That is exactly what I needed. I was not aware of ffill and was struggling what to look up.